# Left join in the hazelcast jet

Tags: java, hazelcast-jet

I'm using the Hazelcast Jet in My application.

```
        // value1
        BatchStageWithKey<Map<String, Object>, Object> indianCustomerJson = value
                .filter(model -> model.nationName().equals("india"))
                .map(model -> JsonUtil.mapFrom(model.getJson_value()))
                .groupingKey(p_json -> p_json.get("id"));

        // value2
        BatchStageWithKey<Map<String, Object>, Object> usaCustomerJson = value
                .filter(model -> model.nationName().equals("usa"))
                .map(model -> JsonUtil.mapFrom(model.getJson_value()))
                .groupingKey(j_json -> j_json.get("id"));
```

Here I have two BatchStageWithKey results.

Now I looking to do the left join like

```
from indianCustomerJson left join usaCustomerJson
```

based on the BatchStageKey

Answer (score 0):

Joins are done manually in Hazelcast Jet. You can either do a hash join or co-group, see these examples: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/tree/master/examples#joins